# Webpack external amd dependecy loading on demand

Tags: requirejs, webpack, amd

My app uses external dependency **simple/app**. I have webpack config property libraryTarget set to 'amd', so my output bundled file looks as follows:

```
define("ApplicationView", ["jquery", "simple/app"], ($, simpleApp) => { 
    ...
});
```

But it leads to external dependency - my **ApplicationView** not start before **simple/app** loaded.
To solve this problem I want to require **simple/app** on demand.

If I will not use webpack code should be like:

```
require(['simple/app'], (simpleApp) => {
...
});
```

But I can't do this with webpack.

webpack's **require.ensure()** didn't help because it works only with local dependencies.

One solution is to use **eval**, but this is very bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution - webpack process **require** method but not **requirejs**, but they work same way, so I use **requirejs** to load external dependency on demand.